# How to import a function in one module to a module in a different folder?

Tags: python, import, package

Imagine a package with this structure:

```
└── main_package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── subpackage1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── module1.py
    └── subpackage2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module2.py
```

What is the best way of importing a function in `module1` to `module2`?

Should the `__init__.py` files contain something?

The best solution I have found is to include in `module2`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
from main_package.subpackage1.module1 import fun1
```

And when running `module2` from the directory in which `main_package` is it works.

But I feel like this does not take advantage of the fact that they are packages. And also it would be nice to be able to run this from wherever I want if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching a video https://youtu.be/U2OcGe-qSEY, I thought of coming back to this question. Well, you don't need much. If you are not going to use the subpackages 1 and 2 independently later, then you even don't need the `__init__.py` file in those two folders. You also don't need the `main.py` file in my old answer. You even don't need to write anything inside the `__init__.py` file of the main package for the purpose of calling functions of the files in this project inside different parts. You can also avoid the `import sys; sys.path.append('./')` in `module2.py`. What you need is just a relative path with respect to the main package. So at the top of `module2.py` you can write `from ..subpackage1.module1 import fun1`. From left to right, we first see a double dot, the first dot in the right says look at the folder containing this file, which is `subpackage2`, then the second dot behind it says go one folder up, so now we are in `main_package`, then it says go to `subpackage1`, and then `module1` and then pick up `fun1` with the same name so in this file you can simply call `fun1`.

Now if you import main_package somewhere else, you have access to everything. Of course you have to call the functions with their intermediate subpackages. If you want to call them as immediate belongings of `main_package`, then you can put those import lines of my old answer in the `__init__.py` file of main package so you can call them as `main_package.fun1` and not `from main_package.subpackage1 import fun1`.

---

**Old answer**:

In Maple importing a module in the main file of your module will automatically share it with the other files and submodules of your module. You can also call the functions that you defined in different files of the same module as far as you have linked them by just including the address to the files of the module in the main file. So you only type the addresses in one file and you do not need to write them in other files of your module. In my opinion that makes life very easier.

In Python I couldn't do the same as in Maple and here is what I do in my current practice. Let me explain on a toy example. There is a folder containing a python file `main.py` and the package structure as you showed in your question. The content of each file is as follows.

main.py

```py
import main_package

main_package.fun2()
```

The `__init__.py` of `main_package`.

```py
from .subpackage1.module1 import fun1
from .subpackage2.module2 import fun2
```

The two init files of subpackages are empty.

module1.py

```py
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
def fun1(polynomial):
    return(sympy.degree(polynomial, gen = x))
```

module2.py

```py
import sympy
from ..subpackage1.module1 import fun1
def fun2():
    polynomial = sympy.sympify(input("Type a univariate polynomial with the variable x and integer coefficients:"))
    print(f"Degree of your polynomial in x is {fun1(polynomial)}.")
```

Now, instead of running the `__init__.py` of `main_package`, I run `main.py` in my VSCode. Note that my main.py file is next to main_package folder, not inside of it.

Again, I think it is sad that I have to write `import sympy` in each of the two files `module1.py` and `module2.py`.
I am very interested if someone someday shows a way so that one can write `import sympy` and `x = sympy.Symbol('x')` only in the top parent `__init__.py` and avoid writing it in the two files `module1.py` and `module2.py`.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable is to always use absolute imports. In this case for module 1:

```py
from MainPackage.module2 import some_function
```

In `module1_1` that would be:

```py
from MainPackage.Subpackage2.module2_1 import some_function
```

Note that the package naming convention is to have all lower case letters and in between words, an underscore (`_`) can be used. In your specific example, `MainPackage` would become `main_package` and so on.

Comment: First of all, thanks for letting me know about the package naming conventions. 
But this gives me the error "No module named 'MainPackage'".
I could use `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` but I was trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Then ommit the `MainPackage`. So for example 1: `from module2 import some_function`.

Comment: That works for the first question. How would that work for the second question? I tried things like: `from .. import Subpackage2`, `from ..Subpackage2 import module2_1`, ... but I get the error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I have not found anything that works.

Comment: You are trying relative imports. Those can get messy quite fast. You would have to do ` from Subpackage2.module2_1 import some_function`.

Comment: That doesn't work, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Subpackage2'`. I think that that is only allowed if the package or the module is a sibling of the file you're working on.

Comment: It depends on where the file resides which you execute. If you start from the root folder (some base launch script), then it should work. If you execute the `module2_1` straight, then indeed that won't work. Then your project structure makes no sense.

Comment: My project structure is as shown in the question. How should it be for it to make sense?

Answer (score 2):

For your first question:

> What is the best way of importing a function in module1 to module2?

You may either use relative or absolute imports. Personally, I prefer to use relative imports *only* within the context of a package I'm working on - to me this highlights when internal packages are related. In addition (and this is environment specific), certain environments will not recognize `main_package` until you install the package (i.e. with `pip install -e .` during development).

Absolute import in module2: `from main_package.subpackage1.module1 import my_function`
Relative import in module2: `from ..subpackage1.module1 import my_function`

For your second question:

> Should the **init**.py files contain something?

They can, and that may provide you with shortcuts for imports. It is common practice to expose general and/or first-class functions/classes on the package level, which essentially is just importing them in `__init__.py`.
For example, in `subpackage1\__init__.py` you could:

```py
from .module1 import my_function
```

And then in `subpackage2\module2.py`, you could simply use `from ..subpackage1 import my_function` (relative import) or `from main_package.subpackage1 import my_function`.

You may also be interested in the topic from the original Python documentation - [import/submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules), [Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) (for additional reading on the import system, followed by intra-package imports), [PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports) (the rationale for relative imports) and [Guido's thoughts regardings relative imports](https://bugs.python.org/issue10031).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Do you know any environments that would recognize `main_package` without installing it?

Comment: I'm not aware of such. The Python import system will look up modules in the current working directory, so if you're running your code from the folder containing `main_package`, it won't be an issue. As I mentioned, I prefer the relative import for intra-module imports - it makes it clear that `module1` and `module2` are related and not part of a 3rd party module.